# What is the VBA property for: Server folder contains x items?

Tags: vba, outlook

I like to compare the amount of items in each folder on the Exchange server with the amount of items in my local Outlook file.

In Outlook I can use the following to get the item count per folder

```
Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set Folder = objNS.Folders("xxx").Folders("Inbox")
Debug.Print Folder.Items.Count
```

How do I get the item count on the server like in the following screenshot?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To find out the number of items in a server (online) folder, you will need to open that folder in the online mode.

In Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) you would need to use the `MAPI_NO_CACHE` bit when calling `IMAPISession::OpenEntry` - you can play with that bit in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author): click IMAPIFolder button, select PR_ENTRYID property, right click, select IMAPISession::OpenEntry, make sure MAPI_NO_CACHE is checked. One you do that, you can retrieve the count either from the `IMAPITable` contents table or by reading the `PR_CONTENT_COUNT` (0x36020003) MAPI property from the folder itself.

Outlook Object Model will not let you override the caching mode on the per folder/message level - the whole profile must have the right connection mode.

In case of languages other than C++ or Delphi, you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am also its author) - its versions of `GetFolderFromID`, `GetMessageFromID`, etc. allow to pass flags to be used by `IMAPISession::OpenEntry`.

```
MAPI_NO_CACHE = &H0200
MAPI_BEST_ACCESS = &H0010
set OomFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set RdoFolder = Session.GetFolderFromID(OomFolder.EntryID, , MAPI_NO_CACHE Or MAPI_BEST_ACCESS)
MsgBox "Number of items in the online folder: " & RdoFolder.Items.Count
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I won't be able to test it so I won't mark it as the answer. Your answer inspired me to a work-around: I just setup the same email account one more time in online mode and then I can count the mails in each folder (which will be exactly like on the server) with the code above. Then I can compare that to the local folders in the offline account. That is no perfect solution but it will do the job.